# add item to cart without popping "order quantity" button

Tags: android

Need Help,
          I am customising an eCommerce app .
Problem: When I select item n press buy button (id=btnadd), A dialogue box pops up asking me to enter order quantity. if I enter 1 and press add, it adds 1 unit to the cart. I don't want to enter quantity at all.It should add a unit of that item and go to cart page.

What I want to do: Press buy button n article should get added to cart and page should also go to cart page. I don't want order quantity popup. By default a single quantity should get added without asking me.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

my code here:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_detail);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);


    // event listener to handle add button when clicked
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // show input dialog
            inputDialog();
        }
    });

}

// method to show number of order form
void inputDialog(){

    // open database first
    try{
        dbhelper.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle(R.string.order);
    alert.setMessage(R.string.number_order);
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    final EditText edtQuantity = new EditText(this);
    int maxLength = 3;    
    edtQuantity.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
    edtQuantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    alert.setView(edtQuantity);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        String temp = edtQuantity.getText().toString();
        int quantity = 0;

        // when add button clicked add menu to order table in database
        if(!temp.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            if(dbhelper.isDataExist(Menu_ID)){
                    dbhelper.updateData(Menu_ID, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
                }else{
                    dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
                }
        }else{
            dialog.cancel();
        }                   
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            // when cancel button clicked close dialog
            dialog.cancel();
      }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain when the quantity dialog should popup and when not?

Comment: I want it not to popup at all.. it sud take only 1 quantity by default.

Comment: @siddheshdighe I want to eliminate this step where user gets a dialogu box to enter quantity. The app will be used for a single quantity only. So Its not good to ask for quantity to enter. I can completly remove the code to stop popup but then It will not add quantity to cart. Pressing buy button sud add single quantity of that item to cart. That is only I want. did i made it clear?

Comment: As far as I understood, the actual behavior is: when user clicks on button, a dialog appears, he writes the quantity and then it goes to another page with the quantity wrote.

Nevertheless, you want the behavior to be: when user clicks on button, it goes to another page with quantity = 1. Is this what you want?

Comment: @RenanBandeira yes,exactly.plz help me out here.

Comment: I'm currently developing a app like this. Which that exactly want you want. Only select items and then goes to a details view where you change the quantity. It is hosted in bitbucket. Let me know and I could send you a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this method instead :-

```
void addtoCart(){

// open database first
try{
    dbhelper.openDataBase();
}catch(SQLException sqle){
    throw sqle;
}

 if(dbhelper.isDataExist(Menu_ID)){
                dbhelper.updateData(Menu_ID, 1, (Menu_price));
            }else{
                dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, 1, (Menu_price));
            }

}
```

Like this in your button on click:-

```
   btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // show input dialog
        addtoCart();
       startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CartActivity.class));

    }
});

}
```

Comment: This worked, Thank you bro. It adds single quantity to the cart. One more thing, how to add intent to that buy button such that it goes to cart activity class.

Comment: check edited answer for :- how to add intent to that buy button such that it goes to cart activity class

Answer (score 0):

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        // show input dialog 
try{ 
    dbhelper.openDataBase(); 
}catch(SQLException sqle){ 
    throw sqle; 
} 

int quantity = 1;

    // when add button clicked add menu to order table in database 
    if(!temp.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        if(dbhelper.isDataExist(Menu_ID)){ 
                dbhelper.updateData(Menu_ID, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
            }else{ 
                dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
            } 

         //To start your Cart Activity after data is updated. (Use getActivty() instead of CurrentActivity.this if you are doing this on Fragment)  
         startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,Your_cart_Activity.class));

    } 
});
```

You can do this directly in your onClick and Call your cart Activity using Intent

Comment: Trying it, will let you know in a minute. Sud I remove all other codes which calls dialogue popup. could you let me know where to do this in above code. Novice here.

Comment: Tried the solution posted by karacken and it worked. Used your suggested intent code in his code. Working perfectly. thanks for helping me.